# When Reduce yields False for a system of inequalities, can I take this as a formal proof?

Tags: inequalities, proof

As part of the proof of a proposition in an economics paper, I need to show that a system of inequalities in four variables is inconsistent. Because the system is complicated, I cannot show this analytically. However, 
`Reduce[System,{x1, x2, x3, x4}, Reals]` returns `False`. Is it acceptable to use this result as part of the formal proof of my proposition? That is, is the algorithm that `Reduce` uses exact? Or does it use short-cuts, approximations, etc.?

Comment: It is certainly a verification if you accept that `Reduce` has no bugs that are affecting its evaluation of your inequalities. Whether or not citing the results in a paper will be accepted, is a something the journal editor will decide. It is not an issue for this site.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it acceptable to use this result as part of the formal proof of my
>   proposition?

In general, no... Mathematica has bugs and problems with differences between its interpretation of things vs. what users may expect. A better approach would be to post the equations or describe them to see what form they take and find out if anyone knows a way to prove they're inconsistent. For instance, it's entirely possible someone may know what algorithm `Reduce` will use to prove your inequalities, and you may be able to reproduce what it does in more straightforwardly provable steps.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question can be broken down into: A) Is Reduce meant to be exact? and B) Are bugs impossible or at least no more likely than mistakes in existing theorems that one can invoke in a proof? Anything other than "Yes" on both question means that I cannot use the results of Reduce in a formal proof. I think you are saying that the answer is "No" to the second question. As to posting the inequalities: There are several systems and many of them involve long, complicated expressions. I don't think I can expect anyone to wade through them. And there's probably no magic trick.